# In memory graph queries

Tags: java, neo4j

I have a Java application which is doing a lot of requests to Neo4j, and I would like to relieve Neo4j a bit to perform some operations like find, filter, sort, limit directly in RAM. In this case, I would like to query Neo4j only when needed to initially fill my in memory cache, and then be able to do graph research without calling Neo4j again.
I see two solutions :

- Use a library which provides a graph data-structure like JGraphT or Guava Graph in combination with lambdas
- Use Apache Spark with GraphX via neo4j-spark-connector

Which one is better or do you see another alternative ?